# Cordova: You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Tags: node.js, cordova

On Linux Mint 17.1 x86_64, Cordova v4.3.0 gives this error:

```
$ cordova run android

Running command: /home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/run 
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Sample
Waiting for emulator...
Booting up emulator (this may take a while)....BOOT COMPLETE

/home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/opt/software/android-sdk/tools/tools/lib/build.template'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
    at /home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:129:40
    at _fulfilled (/home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/naman/test/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

PATH variable seems to be alright (the path for SDK is correct):

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/software/android-sdk/tools:/opt/software/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

I installed it using :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
npm install -g cordova
```

The installation went smoothly and the project was created without any error.
Am I missing some dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have proper environment variables defined (add this in `.bash_login` or `.profile` and do `source .profile`):

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/opt/software/android-sdk"
export ANDROID_NDK="/opt/software/android-ndk"
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

Comment: @gumuruh  He's on Linux, as stated in his original post. Why ask about Windows to a guy that's on Linux ? Maybe you should open up a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: For windows:
add the above same variables in Environment Variables
System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables
example 
variable name : ANDROID_SDK
variable value : /path/android-sdk (remove " ")
and so on...
then close and open your cmd window (runned as admin)

Comment: Where to add all this using Command Line pls guide me through this. i have same problem. but i don't know how to add in `source .profile` where it is ?

Answer (score 18):

You may need to uninstall the existing app on your device.

I installed my app on that device from another computer. When I run `cordova run android` I get

`You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project`.

But when I try to install my apk by `adb` it told my that the app was already installed. So I uninstalled it an it worked.

Comment: I was with the app from the store, when i unistalled it i gone well.

Answer (score 12):

For others having this problem, assuming you have already checked and fixed any environment variables using @Naman Dixit's answer, you may also have to remove and add your platforms:

```
cmd:  cordova platform rm [platform(s) of interest]
```

delete everything in the [yourproject]/platforms folder.  Then:

```
cmd:  cordova platform add [platform(s) of interest]
```

that was the final step I needed to get everything to work

Answer (score 3):

Your android sdk doesn't seem to be properly installed or you didn't install the proper android sdk version that has the dependency that you seem to be missing

```
/opt/software/android-sdk/tools/tools/lib/build.template
```

Comment: Notice the `/tools/tools`? I missed it earlier. Seems I put the wrong $ANDROID_HOME=<>/android-sdk/tools instead of <>/android-sdk. Fixing it solved the issue. Thanks for reposting that one line :-)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue now too. The problem in my case is that the ant.properties file that I'm using is pointed to wrong and NOT existing file.

```
key.store=D:/Fedmich/_keys/android.keystore
```

After correcting it, I was able to compile a release apk.
Hope this helps someone in the future. Just be sure to read the error_logs that is given in the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to have one more reason for this error documented here and for them who are still searching for solution.

When I came accross this error, I tried almost all the solutions listed on the `stackoverflow`.

My issue was my device was not getting detected by `adb`, `adb kill-server/start-server` also not helped me, ***

> but changing `USB` port helped.

---

Answer (score 1):

I got a same error 
my solution is underlying.

1. command adb device
   no result.....
2. install usb drive for mobile (my phone is lg g3)

reeboot and command adb device again : result device showing.
then tried again 
3. ionic run adnroid --device 
"OK";

Answer (score 0):

Happens when platform is added without internet connection.

Ensure internet is OK and type :

> cordova platform remove blackberry10
>
> cordova platform add blackberry10

Try to build and run :

> cordova run

Hope this fix your problem, also for other platform

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after installing the [Crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview). To solve it I installed the latest Android SDK, deleted the android folder under platforms and ran

`phonegap build android`

alternatively

`cordova platform add --save android`

`cordova build android`

and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error building the android platform, and no solution given here could help me.
I decided to run the gradlew command shown by cordova, and saw there was a problem with a png file included in the cordova project.
After removing it, I managed building the platform again.

Answer (score 0):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

then cordova run android works

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu

If you are having issues on Ubuntu, you may want to try installing the following packages, [per the docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

You [may also need to install](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-failed/32069/7) this package:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```