# Cordova : Unable to install apk after upgrading android to 5.1.1 Nexus 5

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Unable to run apk on nexus 5 after upgrading to 5.1.1

Using Cordova: 5.0.0
Device : Nexus 5
Machine : MAC

```html
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.432 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/android/kaljacobs/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/android/kaljacobs/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Installing app on device...

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/android/kaljacobs/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/android/kaljacobs/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Comment: change api level 21 to 22, i don't know what is used to change this in Cordova

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i already updated to Android 5.1.1 API 22 in Android SDK Manager

Comment: i see this line in your question : "You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project", i think you have to update you Cordova API or SDK (whatever) or first check Cordova support android 5.1.1??? also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29721410/1168654

Comment: "You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project" is just a generic message when something goes wrong. (I think cordova devs put this message because most of building issues are caused by sdk not installed or not configured properly)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think you have this issue because the app is installed on your device with a different signature.

When you do cordova run android, the app is installed with a debug signature and maybe that signature changed when you changed target sdk or when you upgraded android.

The fix when you have INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE error is to first uninstall your app and then you should not have the issue any-more when launching `cordova run android`

Comment: The debug package installed on device could has been generated from different computer, so different signature.

Comment: That was exactly the issue I was facing. I had a previous version of the app which was installed while I was debugging from another computer. When I tried to debug the same project on a new computer, the build wasn't sucessful. I simply uninstalled the app from my Android and installed the app again using visual studio (F5).

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about that.for NEXUS 5.go to Settings>> apps>> search application.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Well done..