# Meteor 1.3.3. Build error with android-device

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, build

This is my first question on stackoverflow so I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I'm currently developing a hybrid app using Meteor and its Cordova integration. This is my very first app with Meteor and I use a Mac Mini for dev (1,4 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 Gb ram).

My first builds for Android device were perfectly working in the begining, then I continued the days after with dev builds on iPhone (which were and are still fine). I recently tried to deploy on Android device and it wont build anymore.

I searched the web about my issue but couldn't find anything.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
load: 1.69  cmd: mongod 643 waiting 0.13u 0.41s
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-camera@0.3.2, but it
         should have a minimum version of 2.1.1 to ensure compatibility with
         the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for
         convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-device@0.3.0, but it
         should have a minimum version of 1.1.1 to ensure compatibility with
         the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for
         convenience, but you should adjust your dependencies.
% Notice: nl.x-services.plugins.actionsheet has been automatically converted to cordova-plugin-actionsheet and fetched from npm. This is due to our old plugins registry shutting down.
% Notice: nl.x-services.plugins.actionsheet has been automatically converted to cordova-plugin-actionsheet and fetched from npm. This is due to our old plugins registry shutting down.

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be
         able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the
         same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to
         talk to each other (no client isolation).
I20160622-09:22:24.228(2)? ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20160622-09:22:25.036(2)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
I20160622-09:22:25.037(2)? ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
I20160622-09:22:25.038(2)? ** will still be sent to all clients.
I20160622-09:22:25.038(2)? **                 
I20160622-09:22:25.038(2)? ** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
I20160622-09:22:25.039(2)? **                 
I20160622-09:22:25.039(2)? **   $ meteor remove autopublish
I20160622-09:22:25.040(2)? **                 
I20160622-09:22:25.040(2)? ** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
I20160622-09:22:25.040(2)? ** for each collection that you want clients to see.
I20160622-09:22:25.041(2)?                    
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --device
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
   { [CordovaError: Failed to install apk to device: pkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]]
   name: 'CordovaError',
   message: 'Failed to install apk to device: pkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk\r\nFailure
   [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]',
   code: 0,
   context: undefined } 'Failed to install apk to device: pkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk\r\nFailure
   [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]\n    at
   /Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/lib/Adb.js:67:29\n
   at _fulfilled
   (/Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)\n
   at self.promiseDispatch.done
   (/Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)\n
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)\n
   at
   /Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44\n
   at runSingle
   (/Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)\n
   at flush
   (/Users/naim/Code/apps/live/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)\n
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

/Users/naim/.meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.1.0.1l18108++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Did I miss something that might be obvious to some of you guys?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok I just found some topic on this very site which helped me out for my build issue ... Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502403/cordova-unable-to-install-apk-after-upgrading-android-to-5-1-1-nexus-5 . It was related to the fact that my Android OS was updated between working and failing builds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found some topic on this very site which helped me out for my build issue ... Here is the link : [Cordova : Unable to install apk after upgrading android to 5.1.1 Nexus 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502403/)… . It was related to the fact that my Android OS was updated between working and failing builds. Here's what put me back on tracks:

```
{ [CordovaError: Failed to install apk to device: pkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]]
   name: 'CordovaError',
   message: 'Failed to install apk to device: pkg:
   /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk\r\nFailure [...]
```

What you have to do when you encounter the kind of error I faced is to delete the app from your device before building it again.