# Cordova cannot build Android project using NPM CLI. failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, npm, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Cordova cannot add Android project using NPM CLI. failed with exit code ENOENT. I have installed ANT, ANDROID_HOME and java variables. Please see the screenshot

Error: http://s7.postimg.org/531wg4n6z/Untitled.png

Environment Variables: http://s16.postimg.org/6jgpp3bxh/Untitled.png

Comment: Please see the screen shot http://postimg.org/image/iibga13of/

Comment: Please post stacktrace with this error code (ENOENT). The more information you'll attach, the faster and better answer you'll receive. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try the suggestions from the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721410/cordova-you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-this-project. Mainly, you should make sure your PATH environment includes the Android SDK path, and remove/re-add the 'android' platform using the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of an error but i'm not sure is that the same. because you didn't give much details about your error. but for me, i reinstall cordova then update it.after that its worked as a charm. try the following steps

---

1.run the command: npm uninstall cordova -g

2.delete the folder: C:\Users\your-name.cordova

3.reinstall the cordova: npm install -g cordova

4.now go to the project folder and try again: cordova platform add android

5.npm update -g cordova.

---

try this and let us know. thank you.