# Visual Studio Cordova - You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Tags: android, cordova, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2015 Community - Apache Cordova. I try to run a simple application both in Debug mode as in Release mode and is generated the following error:

```
*2>  ANDROID_HOME=F:\AndroidSDK
2>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
2>C:\Temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
2>throw e;
2>^
2>Error: Device communication timed out. Try unplugging & replugging the device.
2>at null._onTimeout (C:\Temp\Excluir\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1717:25)
2>at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
2>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --target=169.254.138.177:5555 --debug --buildConfig=C:\Temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json"
2>  ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
2>  You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
2>  
2>C:\Temp\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========*
```

My AndroidSDK is complete (with all APIs and extras) . The path is correct for my AndroidSDK . Already tried to run on other versions of Android and the error is the same. In Visual studio I have made ​​clear cordova cache and deleted folders and created a new project. Already reinstalled Apache Cordova. The emulators are using Hyper V and operate correctly. My Windows is 10 64 bits.

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: I think you can read this question, pay attention to the comment for Windows environment at the accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721410/cordova-you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-this-project)

Comment: The real error here is **">Error: Device communication timed out. Try unplugging & replugging the device."** The "You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project" is a generic message.  Are you trying to run this on the VS Android emulator or an actual Android device?  If a device, be sure you have the actual Windows driver for your device installed - The Google works on Nexus devices but often not others (most notable Samsung).  You can also try running "adb kill-server" followed by "adb start-server" to try to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real problem: Timeout.

I do not know what causes this problem, but I have a possible solution.

Folder: platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q

File: q.js

**Line:**   deferred.reject(new Error(message || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms"));
    }, ms);

**Modify:** deferred.reject(new Error(message || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms"));
    }, 40000);

However, in my case I have finished running manually (shortcut key: Ctrl + Break), as the figure:
[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzehe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that helped me is to run this commands in terminal:

```
cordova clean
cordova build
cordova run android
```

After this no more:

```
Error: Device communication timed out. Try unplugging & replugging the device
```