# Ionic run error exit code 1 device communication timed out

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently started getting this error when trying to run any Cordova project, whether it is Ionic or just a plain Cordova project.

It allows me to build the project without any issues but if I try to use the commands `ionic run android` or `cordova run android` to push to a device or emulator I get the error below:

[image: Error message received through CLI]

I have worked on and can confirm that it was working yesterday.
Nothing changed in the mean time. This is on a Windows machine. I have formatted and reinstalled everything which helped for a day then I started receiving the same errors.

```
NPM version 2.14.12
Ionic version 1.7.12
Cordova version 5.4.1
Java version 1.8.0_66
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hack to solve this (but not a real solution) is to modify file `platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js` on line `1716-1718`

From this:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
  deferred.reject(new Error(message || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms"));
}, ms);
```

To this:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
  deferred.reject(new Error(message || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms"));
}, 15000);
```

*This hack comes from this other stackoverflow question: [Visual Studio Cordova - You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054303/visual-studio-cordova-you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-t) ,
I didn't mark this one as duplicate because of this better question explanation here.*

Comment: Thanks bertandg. This solves the issue. Seems that it just needs more time building for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I changed it

```
Promise.prototype.timeout = function (ms, error) {
    var deferred = defer();
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        if (!error || "string" === typeof error) {
            error = new Error(error || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms");
            error.code = "ETIMEDOUT";
        }
        deferred.reject(error);
    }, 15000);
```

//change from ms to 15000 - Rakesh Kumar Jha - 10-04-2017

but still after BUILD SUCCESSFUL, application is not launching in device

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 7.304 secs
Built the following apk(s):

C:/Rakesh_Kumar_Jha/BCodeScanApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\kumarjha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

No target specified, deploying to device '494faea'.
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):

C:/Rakesh_Kumar_Jha/BCodeScanApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Using apk: 

C:/Rakesh_Kumar_Jha/BCodeScanApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Package name: com.rakesh.jha
```

- after package name: com.rakesh.jha, nothing is comming, CLI is stuck at com.rakesh.jha