# Ionic 3 CordovaError: Device communication timed out. Try unplugging & replugging the device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been getting this error recently. I have no idea why it's happening. Everything used to work fine and now for no apparent reason, the app won't deploy on the device anymore. 
I already tried the solution from this post but still no luck.

[Ionic run error exit code 1 device communication timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684116/ionic-run-error-exit-code-1-device-communication-timed-out)

I get the error every time I run the ionic cordova run android command.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
47 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 46 up-to-date

Built the following apk(s):

C:\wamp64\www\afghanjam\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app- 
debug.apk

 ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Hamid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_102
 No target specified, deploying to device 'LGH81539ab6482'.

 **(node:8400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
 (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Device communication timed out. Try 
 unplugging & replugging the device.**

 (node:8400) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
 deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
 terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

 [OK] Your app has been deployed.
 Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I tried to removing android and adding it back from the platform list.
Tried also uninstalling the phone from the computer and installing it again from device manager to update the drivers and still no luck.

Comment: did you solved?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a tricky workaround:

1. Go to: `\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q`
2. Locate:

   ```
   var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {deferred.reject(new
   Error(message || “Timed out after " + ms + " ms”)); }, ms);
   ```
3. Change to:

   ```
   var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
   deferred.reject(new Error(message || “Timed out after " + ms + "
   ms”)); }, 600000); //10 minutes before timing out
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem that sometimes logged this device error and other times logged cordova plugin problems or jdk not correctly installed error.

The error that I was talking about:

> Device communication timed out. Try 
>    unplugging & replugging the device.**"
>
> Execute program failed with exit code 3221225794.

I successfully fixed it by running the following command that fixes all DLL problems on Windows, and then restarting the computer.
From powershell, admin may be required:

```
sfc /scannow
```