# You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project - Cordova - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working with Cordova to build my mobile app. I'm working on a Mac machine and when I try to build and run my app on iOS device, but I'm keep  getting this error.

When running:

```
cordova build ios
```

output:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

then I run

```
cordova run ios
```

I get the error

```
.../ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

If I try to open the project in Xcode and run it, it successfully run on the device.

I notice that before the run failed, it output the message

```
ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install 'npm install -g ios-sim'
```

I'm guessing Cordova thinks the device isn't plugged in since the `ios-sim` is a simulatur plugin for cordvoa. But I may be wrong.

Any ideas?

(This question is similar to [Cordova: You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721410/cordova-you-may-not-have-the-required-environment-or-os-to-run-this-project), but this question regarding iOS there that Android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
npm install -g ios-sim
npm install -g ios-deploy
```

I suggest you read [iOS Platform guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html) for more info.

Comment: After running these command and then trying to deploy to device using `$ cordova run ios` the simulator opens, instead of installing the app on the connected device. Can I deploy the app to device from the CLI, or I must use Xcode?

Comment: cordova run ios --device